# Identification of cylindrical part with unknown purpose

Tags: ceramics, part-identification

I came across some of these parts and have no idea what they are. It could be related to bearings, but most likely not. I also have other, similar looking parts but of all different dimensions (with the same shape). Material feels quite hard, almost like ceramic, and is cold to the touch. I am based in the United Kingdom (if that helps). Seems to me custom made to required size (as there is a customer identification number). I have also included a photo of how they are packed and the label on the box

Text on the part itself and the label on the box:

- GC800-70GV2S
- 1909177
- 50/30 x 45 x 16mm

I am looking to find out what these parts are and their application.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where did you find them? What does the company / business make? That may help identify them, also they may be rollers for paper delivery given the surface finish.

Comment: I got them as part of a job lot of assorted items at a general auction. So, there is no information about the company or business who manufactures or sell them.

Comment: The p/n GC800-70GV2S is listed here: https://www.darmann.com/specifications/product-selection/    Looks like some kind of abrasive shaping or surface finishing tool for production of hip implants ????

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. This is exactly the correct solution. As I mentioned, I have many different part numbers of these but just got unlucky. I didn't search all of the part numbers - the ones I did search didn't have any results, but the one I posted here is listed! @PeteW if you want to convert your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: And if you want to help someone looking for those part numbers that you did not list, as you were doing in the past, list them in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The p/n GC800-70GV2S is listed here:

[darmann.com/specifications/product-selection](https://darmann.com/specifications/product-selection)

Looks like some kind of abrasive shaping or surface finishing tool for production of hip implants